# My code for "Count only Repeated" is not working. Have written clean code(according to me) that is easy to understand

Tags: arrays, sorting, data-structures, binary-search, array-algorithms

Here is the question : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-of-only-repeated-element-in-a-sorted-array-of-consecutive-elements/

Here is my code :

```
public static Point findRepeating(Integer arr[],int n)
{
    // Point(return type) is a class having first and second as data memebres where first is number  
    // repeating and second is number of times it is repeating

    if(arr[0] == arr[n-1])              // whole array has only one number 
        return new Point(arr[0],n);
        
    int low = 0,high = n-1,mid = (low+high)/2, repNumber = 0;
    
    while(high-low > 1)       // in this loop only I'm trying to find the number that is repeating
    {
        mid = (low+high)/2;
        
        if(arr[mid] == arr[mid-1] || arr[mid] == arr[mid+1])
        {
            repNumber = arr[mid];
            break;
        }
        
        if((arr[low]+(mid-low)) == arr[mid])
            low = mid+1;
        else
            high = mid;
    }
    int startIndex=0,endIndex=0;
    // now I'll find the start and end index of the repeating number
    // doing this by finding number just smaller and just larger than repeating number
    if(repNumber == arr[0])
    {
        startIndex = 0;
        endIndex = Arrays.binarySearch(arr,repNumber+1);
        return new Point(repNumber,endIndex);
    }
    if(repNumber == arr[n-1])
    {
        endIndex = n-1;
        startIndex = Arrays.binarySearch(arr,repNumber-1);
        return new Point(repNumber,endIndex-startIndex);
    }
    else
    {
        startIndex = Arrays.binarySearch(arr,repNumber-1) + 1;
        endIndex = Arrays.binarySearch(arr,repNumber+1);
        return new Point(repNumber,endIndex-startIndex);
    }
}
```

The test case where my code fails is(whole input is not visbile as it's huge):

Wrong Answer. !!!Wrong Answer

Possibly your code doesn't work correctly for multiple test-cases (TCs).

The first test case where your code failed:

Input:
28566
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 15.................

Its Correct output is:
16932 10086

And Your Code's output is:
0 0

Comment: Its working perfectly fine on my machine. Perhaps you can give me some submission link of the problem or maybe your implementation of `Point` class has some problem.

Comment: @risingStark Thanks a lot for the reply. Actually I've bought Geeksforgeeks DSA course so you won't be able to access that submission link. Please look at the above link. It is exactly similar. Just the argument is having vector whereas the actual question is having Integer array and it's size as input. Btw the link is https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/count-only-repeated2047/1/?track=SPC-Searching&batchId=140 if you can access. Thanks

Comment: The link as you stated is not accessible. You can first try running the trivial testcases to see if the code is failing for this particular test case or any of the testcase. I guess there must be some custom test feature. There you can input trivial testcases and this test case as well. I have the [test case](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sY_ksdJ26oXpJYq7BdjqspqR6s28Bem2/view?usp=sharing) on which your code is failing.

Comment: @risingStark yes there is custom test input available but frankly speaking I don't know what "trivial testcases" mean. Is is like checking for some custom inputs and corner cases which I can evaluate on my own to cross check with my code's output ? Also how did you extracted that test case where my code is failing ? Is it any feature or you observed the expected output and generated the test case ?

Comment: I generated the test case as the input size was given, all elements should have been consecutive and also the repeating element's info was given. And you are right about trivial test cases, Run some of them and see if your code is behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This question can be simply solved using Linear Search within Time Complexity less than O(N) ( **O(N) in worst case** ).
In first step we can check whether the first and last element of array are equal or not?

If Yes,
We can return the size of array as our answer.
Otherwise we can check Linearly using two methods

Method 1  : **We can take the consecutive Differences between two Numbers and check whether they give us Zero as result or not**

```
     int count = 0;
     vector<int>arr = { 1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3 }; 
for(int i = 0; i < arr.size() ; i++){
    if(arr[i+1] - arr[i] == 0 ){
        count++;
    }
}
```

Method 2  : **By Taking XOR of two consecutive elements of array and When XOR is zero increment the count**

```
int count = 0;
vector<int>arr = { 1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3 }; 
 for(int i = 0; i < arr.size() ; i++){
    if((arr[i+1]^arr[i]) == 0 ){
        count++;
    }
}
```